# Which tool can extract this kind of comments?

Tags: c, comments

Hi I recently found there are some special comments in the code, but it is not doxygen style,  can anyone tell me what tool can extract this kind of comments?

```
/*
 @doc INTERNAL
 @func  ULONG | SerialDispatchThread | Main serial event dispatch thread code.
 *  This is the reading and dispatching thread. It gets the
 *  event associated with the logical interrupt dwIntID and calls
 *  hardware specific routines to determine whether it's a receive event
 *  or a transmit event. If it's a transmit event, it calls the HW tx handler.
 *  If it's a receive event, it calls for the number of characters and calls
 *  atomic GetByte() to extract characters and put them into the drivers
 *  buffer represented by pSerialHead->pTargetBuffer, managing waiting
 *  for events and checking to see if those signals correspond to reading.
 *  It relies on NK masking the interrupts while it does it's thing, calling
 *  InterruptDone() to unmask them for each of the above cases.
 *
 *  Not exported to users.
 *
 @rdesc This thread technically returns a status, but in practice, doesn't return
 *   while the device is open.
 */
```

I found the download link [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/780/download.aspx), if anyone needs this:)

Comment: if its not doxygen then why you have tagged question as doxygen?

Comment: I think maybe doxygen users know more about these tools. If it's not appropriate, I can delete the tag.

Comment: Why the close vote to this question? It IS a clear question, I'm asking which tool can interpret this kind of comments.

Comment: IMHO this is a good and valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it belongs to [AutoDuck](http://helpmaster.info/hlp-developmentaids-autoduck.htm).

Check [this manual](http://www.literateprogramming.com/autoduck.pdf) of the tool (I could not find much more information...)

Comment: The download link is broken... Seems that this tool is written by a guy who works in M$.

Comment: Oh... I did not check they download link... Hopefully there is another download available!

Comment: Knowing it belongs to AutoDuck is enough:) Thank you very much, I'll find the download myself.